# Format results of a string phone number in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to format the query results of phone numbers so that the phone string has a country code if it is not already in that format.

The DB (MySQL) currently contains phone numbers in two formats. Below is an example of the two ways the phone number is represented:

- local number format, which starts with 07 e.g. 0799123456
- international format, which starts with +111 for the country code, then 7 (without the 0 in front of the 7) e.g. +111799123456

I want the query results to be such that the phone number is in the international format, if it is in the local number format. For example, if the number was stored as 0799123456 the query result should be +111799123456

```
SELECT phone 
FROM customer c, order o
WHERE c.id = o.cust_id
```

How do I manipulate my select statement to return the string in the international format if the phone number is in the local format? Basically, I'm trying to prepend +1117 if the number starts with 07 (so replace the 07 with +1117) in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Just use string functions:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN phone LIKE '07%' THEN INSERT(phone, 1, 1, '+111')
    ELSE phone
END AS phone_formatted
FROM (
    SELECT '0799123456' AS phone UNION
    SELECT '+111799123456'
) x
```

Comment: The OP wanted to concat +111 not +1117
And it should be SUBSTRING(phone, 2, 100) (not 3) ..

Comment: last line says _so replace the 07 with +1117_. Replace 0 with +111 or 07 with +1117 it is the same thing anyway.

Comment: granted, it would be the same but that assumption relies on the fact that all numbers start with 07 - possible, and may be the case today but it's not "future-proof"

Comment: All the numbers start with 07 - and it's true that I need to concatenate +111 not +1117, since the 7 is already in existence.

Comment: @les I've revised the answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
select case when left(phone,2)='07' then 
concat('+1117',substring(phone,3,length(phone)-2)) else phone end as newphone
FROM customer c join `order` o WHERE c.id = o.cust_id
```